# Alternative to mysql WHERE IN SELECT GROUP BY when wanting max value in group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following query, which was developed from a hint found online because of a problem with a `GROUP BY` returning the maximum value; but it's running really slowly.

Having looked online I'm seeing that `WHERE IN (SELECT.... GROUP BY)` is probably the issue, but, to be honest, I'm struggling to find a way around this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_berths a
JOIN tbl_active_trains b on a.train_uid=b.train_uid 
WHERE (a.train_id, a.TimeStamp) in (
    SELECT a.train_id, max(a.TimeStamp) 
    FROM a 
    GROUP BY a.train_id
)
```

I'm thinking I possibly need a derived table, but my experience in this area is zero and it's just not working out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move that to a SUBQUERY and also select only required columns instead of All (*)

```
SELECT a.train_uid
FROM tbl_berths a
JOIN tbl_active_trains b on a.train_uid=b.train_uid 
JOIN  (SELECT a.train_id, max(a.TimeStamp) as TimeStamp
    FROM a 
    GROUP BY a.train_id )T
on a.train_id = T.train_id
and a.TimeStamp = T.TimeStamp
```

Comment: Thanks, this made it around 6-8 times faster execution time